# Customize fonts loading for WebViewer PDFTron

Tags: pdftron

I am using PDFTron and recently i've noticed that by default WebViewer loads many fonts when opening and some of them are hardweight. Maybe anyone knows how to prevent loading some fonts in WebViewer?[image]